# Creating and save text file in assembly

Tags: assembly, masm

I am trying to create new file using assembler language in MASM 6.11 and DOSBox on Windows 7. I have mount drive C, D, E as folders BIN, BINR and palce where are my programs. When I try to run my program in console it get stuck but when I am debbuging it, using CV command process terminated normally. Here is my code:

```
.model small
.stack 100h

.data
    NazwaPliku  db  "dane.txt", 0
    UchwytPliku dw  ?
    Napis db "ASSEMBLER"

.code
        ASSUME cs: @code, ds: @data
        mov ax, @data
        mov ds, ax

main PROC
        MOV AH,3CH
        MOV CX,0
        MOV DX,OFFSET NazwaPliku
        INT 21H 

        MOV AH, 3DH
        MOV AL, 0
        MOV DX, OFFSET NazwaPliku
        INT 21H
        mov UchwytPliku, ax

        MOV AH,40H
        MOV BX, UchwytPliku
        MOV DX,OFFSET Napis
        MOV CX, 5
        INT 21H

        mov ah, 4Ch
        mov al, 0
    int 21h
main ENDP

END main
```

I know that it is very simple program, but I can't get it to work...

Comment: You are opening the file twice, with AH=3Ch and AH=3Dh.

Comment: The initialization of `DS` will not be done. Push the line `main PROC` two lines up.

Comment: Also, you don't seem to set up the access code when opening the file using `int 21h / ah=3Dh`. If you want to open the file for writing you should use `al = 1` or `al = 2`. And when you create the file using `int 21h / ah=3Ch` you should clear `cl` first unless you want any special attributes on the file.

Comment: Thank you guys - everything is working now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your program with corrections

```
.model small
.stack 100h

.data
    NazwaPliku  db  "dane.txt", 0
    UchwytPliku dw  ?
    Napis db "ASSEMBLER"

.code
        ASSUME cs: @code, ds: @data
main PROC
        mov ax, @data              <- Put in the execution path!
        mov ds, ax                 <- so below "main PROC"

        MOV AH,3CH
        MOV CX,0
        MOV DX,OFFSET NazwaPliku
        INT 21H 
        jc fail                    <- In case DOS failed the operation 

        ;MOV AH, 3DH               <- After a succesful creation, the
        ;MOV AL, 1                 <- file is already opened for normal
        ;MOV DX, OFFSET NazwaPliku <- read and write access.
        ;INT 21H
        ;jc fail

        mov UchwytPliku, ax

        MOV AH,40H
        MOV BX, UchwytPliku
        MOV DX,OFFSET Napis
        MOV CX, 5                  <- "ASSEMBLER" has 9 bytes. Typo ?
        INT 21H
        ;jc fail

fail:
        mov ah, 4Ch
        mov al, 0
        int 21h
main ENDP

END main
```

It would be best to display a message whenever the operation failed.

If you really need to open the file explicitely then first close it after it was created.

```
    MOV AH,3CH
    MOV CX,0
    MOV DX,OFFSET NazwaPliku
    INT 21H
    jc fail

    mov bx, ax
    mov ah, 3Eh
    int 21h
    jc fail

    MOV AH, 3DH
    MOV AL, 1
    MOV DX, OFFSET NazwaPliku
    INT 21H
    jc fail
    mov UchwytPliku, ax
```